# Get values from repeated parameter in query string accessing 'parameters' in sourceMap

Tags: javascript, arrays, parameters, query-string, mirth

I'm facing a newbie to Mirth and I'm struggling against an easy problem I think, but I cannot find the solution.
I'm using mirth v3.12.0 and I set an http listener channel that received a GET request with some paramters like this `http://localhost:38081/Observation?identifier=2230106554&issued=ge[2023-07-08 10:00:02.345678]&issued=le[2023-07-08 12:00:02.345678]`
At the destination channel, in the transformer, I want to manage the values associated to the two parameters named 'issued'.

In the mapping I saw that parameters are stored in a variable 'parameters' that looks like an object and every parameter in it looks like an array, but when I try to accesso the 'issued' parameter array I obtain errors.

The code:

```
var issued0;
var issued1;
var issued = sourceMap.get('parameters').get('issued');
issued0 = issued[0];
issued1 = issued[1];
```

the error:

```
478:    issued0 = issued[0];
479:    issued1 = issued[1];
480:    var ge;
481:    var le;
482:    var headIssued0 = issued0.substring(0,2);
483:    var headIssued1 = issued1.substring(0,2);
LINE NUMBER:    479
DETAILS:    Java class "java.lang.String" has no public instance field or method named "0".
    at e0fc6857-357d-4eda-8525-556ac60bba77:479 (doTransform)
    at e0fc6857-357d-4eda-8525-556ac60bba77:788 (doScript)
    at e0fc6857-357d-4eda-8525-556ac60bba77:790
    at com.mirth.connect.server.transformers.JavaScriptFilterTransformer$FilterTransformerTask.doCall(JavaScriptFilterTransformer.java:154)
    at com.mirth.connect.server.transformers.JavaScriptFilterTransformer$FilterTransformerTask.doCall(JavaScriptFilterTransformer.java:119)
    at com.mirth.connect.server.util.javascript.JavaScriptTask.call(JavaScriptTask.java:113)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Comment: query parameters with the same name (`issued`) could indeed bring troubles. In your situation, the error raised by Java tells you `issued` is a string, and you're trying to access it as if it were an array (`issued[0]`, `issued[1]`)

Comment: There is no real standard for this, maybe you could try the PHP way, passing parameters like this: `?issued[]=value1&issued[]=value2`

Comment: @GrafiCode The problem is that I have to follow the specifications of the project, so parameters in the query string must be passed that way.
Looking at the mapping in the destination channel I can see this related to 'parameters' key map:
`{identifier=[2230106554], issued=[ge[2023-07-08 10:00:02.345678], le[2023-07-08 12:00:02.345678]]}`, so I supposed that could be possible to think 'issued' as an array

Comment: what's the output if you debug `issued` after assigning `sourceMap.get('parameters').get('issued')`?

Comment: @GrafiCode the output is only the first issued value, so ge[...]

Comment: ok, from this page: http://javadocs.mirthcorp.com/connect/3.5.0/user-api/com/mirth/connect/userutil/MessageParameters.html  it says `get` method is deprecated. I think you should use `sourceMap.getParameterList('issued')` or maybe `sourceMap.get('parameters').getParameterList('issued')` not sure which one

Comment: @GrafiCode thank you very much, the second snippet suggestion worked!

Comment: glad it worked, unfortunately I don't think I'm skilled enough on this topic to provide a proper answer. Gave your question an upvote, if you reach 15 reputation points you'll be able to self-answer your own question (I think this would be the best scenario)